# Confused about the statistical test to use

Tags: anova

I am a little bit confused about the statistical test I should use. The following is my case:

I am measuring participants' personality traits (agreeableness, extraversion, conscientiousenss, openess, neuroticism) and I asked them how likely it would be that they performed five different actions on a 7-point scale (let's call them A, B, C, D, E). So the data I have are the 5 personality traits that I measure and the 5 response actions on a 7-point scale.

What I want to know is whether the likelihood that they would perform the actions can be explained by the score of each of the personality traits.

For example; someone who scores high on neuroticism is more likely to involve in action A than one of the other actions.

I was thinking of a repeated measures anova as I am measuring 5 times the response action for each participant, but how do I handle the 5 personality traits as they are also with-in subjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood of action is surely the dependent variable.

So one way to do it would be 5 separate ordinal logistic regression models - one for each action.  If you wanted to look at all 5 actions at the same time you would need a multivariate ordinal logistic regression, which is something I have not seen done (but it ought to be possible)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why would a logistic regression do? Each participants gives a score on each of the personality traits. It is not that there is just one trait for one participant. For example; a participant can have agreeableness (2.3), extraversion (3.1), conscientiousenss (4.2), openess (1.2), neuroticism (2). Wouldn't this still be something like a repeated measures even though splitting up the DV's?

Comment: The dependent variable is the score on likelihood of taking an action. This goes from 1 to 7, so that's why you need ordinal logistic. The independent variables would be the personality scores, having multiple independent variables is no problem. There is no repeated measure here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Somehow when I add the personality as IV, it splits all the possible scores participants gave into separate variables instead of just taking the range of each personality trait. So for example, it analyzes extraversion score 1.25 separately, 1.50, 1,63 and so forth instead of taking everything as one

Comment: You have somehow made those variables categorical,